# Subclassing UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes

Tags: ios, ios6, uicollectionview

I recently started playing with the awesome UICollectionView API, making reasonable progress, but have been stuck for almost all day with an issue I'm hoping someone can help me with:

I need to add some custom details to certain cells' attributes.
In order to do this, the right approach seem to be to subclass UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes and add the properties I need to my subclass. So far so good, except that when I return my LayoutAttributesSubclass, I always get the, somehow obscure, following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: key cannot be nil'
```

Having tried to track this down for a while, I'm under the impression that the error is related to representedElementKind and representedElementCategory being nil in my subclass's instance. But those properties are read only, so I can't set those.
I've managed to somehow bypass the error by cheating, getting a regular UICollectionViewAttributes instance, then changing it to a LayoutAttributesSubclass using object_setClass, but this then raises a ton of other issues, plus seems rather shady to me.

In short, does anyone knows what the error above means, and how to correctly create/use UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes subclasses?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When setting up custom attributes, you need to subclass UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *and* subclass UICollectionViewLayout and "declare" your custom attribute subclass class name by overriding +(Class)layoutAttributesClass in your UICollectionViewLayout class. The system calls this class method to see if there is a custom class to be supplied when you use the factory method for instantiating/dequeuing layout attribute objects.

```
@interface YourCustomCollectionViewAttributes : UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes

@property (nonatomic)               UIEdgeInsets        myCustomProperty                        

@end

@interface YourCustomCollectionViewLayout : UICollectionViewLayout

@end

@implementation YourCustomCollectionViewLayout

+ (Class)layoutAttributesClass
{
    return [IRTableCollectionViewLayoutAttributes class];
}

@end
```

This is correct according to the documentation and should prevent the particular error you are having. Also when you implement custom iVars, be sure to implement an override for -(id)copyWithZone: or the UICollectionView will lose any custom values you have applied to your custom collection view object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, +layoutAttributesClass indeed is the way to go. I was hoping for a different solution because I wanted to use my layoutattributes subclass only for some specific items, but apparently it can't be done.

Comment: The issue of dropping custom values is because we have to implement -copyWithZone: because UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes implements and uses NSCopying

Comment: thanks griotspeak, you are quite correct - and so simple. I'll modify my answer to take account of this.

Comment: This does not work for me, I get the NSInvalidArgumentException before  layoutAttributesClass is called, its due to using [[MyCollectionViewLayoutAttributes alloc] init] instead of [MyCollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:indexPath]. I do set the indexPath and have overrided representedElementCategory. Any ideas?

Comment: @griotspeak's copy constructor note is very important. If you notice the attributes you set not "sticking around" until applyLayoutAttributes:, implement a copy constructor.